# Why AsParallel().ForAll does not seem to fully take advantage of the cpu usage for my operations?

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I have some code which attempts to execute an operation in parallel.

The code is basically

```
    items
      .AsParallel()
      .ForAll(item =>
      {
          DoWork(item);
      });
```

Items is a list of 2500 things to process. DoWork() is a 100% CPU calculation with no IO at all. It takes about 1 second however it can vary to some degree.

The problem I am seeing is all cores are being used however they are barely being used. I was thinking it was something to do with the work itself so I tried code like the following and got the same results.

```
    items
      .Batches(10)
      .AsParallel()
      .ForAll(batch =>
      {
          foreach(var item in batch)
          {
            DoWork(item);
          }
      });
```

I want the utilization to be somewhere near 80% however for the life of me I can't get it there. Not sure what to do.

I have tried Parallel.ForEach with no luck. Tried .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount * 2) with no luck.

Not sure what to try next.

[image: CPU utilization]

Comment: AsParallel().ForAll not using all... all what?

Comment: 99% your `DoWork` actually schedules all work back to UI thread or blocks threads in some other way. Please provide true [MCVE].

Comment: It is actually a windows service so there is no UI. I don't think there is any blocking either.

Answer (score 0):

Are the `items` `IEnumerable`? 
If so, you may be experiencing poor partitioning. Try wrapping (or passing) items as an `IList<T>` or just `List<T>`.

Comment: They are an IList.

Answer (score 0):

Are the items constructed/computed on the fly or lazily? 
Maybe the (sequential) source of the items can not deliver them fast enough to make parallelism profitable.

Comment: They are not. I am beginning to think it has to do with the physical machine itself.